# PHP Mailer | Problema al tratar de enviar correos con Gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail, email

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario de registro con confirmacion de contraseña con PHPMailer. Mi codigo de de mis datos de phpmailer

```
function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){

        require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "MiUsuario@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "MiContraseña";

        $mail->setFrom("MiUsuario@gmail.com");

        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
    $mail->addAddress($email);


        if($mail->send())
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
```

En el error al hacer me sale lo siguiente:

```
2018-09-26 14:23:50 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2018-09-26 14:23:50 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Luego, me di cuenta que al abrir mi cuenta de gmail me sale el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le di click a ver actividad, me sale otro mensaje que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se si el problema tiene que ver con los permisos que tiene mi cuenta o si hay alguna manera mejor de solucionar..

Answer (score 1):

Entra en esta URL y permite el acceso a las aplicaciones menos seguras en tu cuenta de gmail. Después vuelve a probar.

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Saludos

Comment: Ahora me llega otro correo a mi gmail, que dice:Se ha activado el acceso para las aplicaciones menos seguras, Si no la has modificado tú, deberías comprobar qué ha sucedido.... Luego le doy de nuevo a ver actividad  y me sale que si he sido yo o que proteja mi cuenta, y le doy a que he sido yo y igual intento y no pasa nada

Comment: Cuanto te llega un mensaje de este tipo, simplemente ignóralo, lo que hay que comprobar es que el envío de mensajes desde tu aplicación php funcione al activar lo de las aplicaciones menos seguras. Haz un mensaje de prueba y envíatelo a ti mismo.

Comment: No tiene que ver que mi hosting solo sea http? que no se pueda enviar correctamente por que no es https

Comment: no tiene nada que ver, yo he usado hostings gratuitos con http a secas y siempre he podido enviar correos